# Indicator column for treatment variable creation

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and am having some trouble adding the indicator column I need. In the picture you can see there is a column labeled "lawchange" I would like to create an indicator column which tells if the state had this law change take place or not (treatment column indicator).

In essence, if there is a "1" in lawchange column anywhere for a given state, I would like that entire state to have an indicator column "treated" saying it is TRUE and if there is not a "1" anywhere in the lawchange column for that state the "treated" column would read FALSE.

```
    year    state   agegr   mrate   lawchange
1   1970    1   15-17 yrs   104.88168   0
2   1970    1   18-20 yrs   153.87047   0
3   1970    1   21-24 yrs   172.95686   0
4   1971    1   15-17 yrs   109.53251   0
5   1971    1   18-20 yrs   161.53520   0
6   1971    1   21-24 yrs   178.49515   0
7   1972    1   15-17 yrs   120.06564   0
8   1972    1   18-20 yrs   159.21349   0
9   1972    1   21-24 yrs   177.87250   0
10  1973    1   15-17 yrs   113.52836   0
11  1973    1   18-20 yrs   140.88599   0
12  1973    1   21-24 yrs   149.36366   0
13  1974    1   15-17 yrs   97.80592    0
14  1974    1   18-20 yrs   143.09831   0
15  1974    1   21-24 yrs   168.53503   0
16  1975    1   15-17 yrs   90.10225    0
17  1975    1   18-20 yrs   147.94107   1  <-- ** see note

** since this state has a 1 in the lawchange column I would 
   like a treatment column to show TRUE for the entire state.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(state) %>%
    summarise(treated=sum(lawchange) > 0) %>%
    right_join(df, by='state')
```

**Edit**:

With `data.table` something like this should work:

```
dt[, c(.SD, treated = sum(lawchange) > 0), by=state]
```

If you prefer in-place modification be sure to check @David Arenburg comment.

Comment: I get the following message: Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: You should replace both occurrences of `df` with actual name of your variable.

Comment: After using this code and applying it to the dataset like this:            
          
          dt.deaths <- df %>% group_by(state) %>% summarise(treated=sum(lawchange) > 0) %> right_join(df, by='state')          
           
I am no longer able to make changes to the rest of my data set, everything else comes back with errors (like when trying to create a new column by adjusting the old one:              

         dt.deaths <- dt.deaths[, logbeertaxa:= log(beertaxa)]Error in `:=`(logbeertaxa, log(beertaxa)) :

Comment: Unfortunately `right_join` returns a `data.frame` not a `data.table`. If you want `data.table` you have to add `as.data.table()`. Generally speaking it is good mention if you use `data.table`. There are many situations when it matters.

Comment: I added `data.table` specific solution as well.

Comment: There is no need to copy `.SD` every time. It is both very inefficient and doesn't update the actual data set. This should be `dt[, treated := sum(lawchange) > 0, by=state]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg You definitely have a point here but somehow I find idea of the mutable data structures rather disturbing. That's why I prefer `dplyr` way.